# how to rename a variable using a dynamic name and dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

I want to rename a column inside a function with a name passed as an argument for this function. Basically, I have a function

```
produce_data_frame <- function(name) {
  return(iris)
}
```

And I want that this function change the Sepal.length column name with 'name' (with name taking the value of name)
I tried different things such as

```
produce_data_frame <- function(name) {
  name <- enquo(name)
  iris %>%
    rename((!!name) = Sepal.Length) %>%
    return()
}
```

And when calling

```
produce_data_frame("newName")
```

I would like to get back the iris data.frame with the Sepal.Length column named newName. But my understanding of NSE is still very basic, and it doesn't even compile.

Comment: not sure what was wrong with my question, I tried to develop my exemple, if this is not the problem, could some one explain what is the problem with it ? Thanks,

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can try

```r
library(tidyverse)

produce_data_frame <- function(name) {
  iris %>%
    as.tibble() %>% 
    select(!!quo_name(name) := Sepal.Length)
}

produce_data_frame("new_name")
#> # A tibble: 150 x 1
#>    new_name
#>       <dbl>
#>  1     5.10
#>  2     4.90
#>  3     4.70
#>  4     4.60
#>  5     5.00
#>  6     5.40
#>  7     4.60
#>  8     5.00
#>  9     4.40
#> 10     4.90
#> # ... with 140 more rows
```

Created on 2018-04-04 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Or you can use`{{...}}`

```r
produce_data_frame <- function(name) {
  iris %>%
    as_tibble() %>% 
    select({{name}} := Sepal.Length)
}
```

Answer (score 25):

From [Different input and output variable](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#different-input-and-output-variable)  in the **Programming with dplyr** vignette, we can use the `:=` operator:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)


produce_data_frame <- function(name) {
  name = quo_name(name)
  iris %>%
    rename(!!name := Sepal.Length)
}

produce_data_frame('test') %>% colnames()
#> [1] "test"         "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 
#> [5] "Species"
```

Comment: This is clean and beautiful!

Comment: I had no idea that dplyr has a walrus operator. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 7):

You can use base R `names()` instead.

```
produce_data_frame <- function(name) {
  temp_df <- iris
  names(temp_df)[names(temp_df) == "Sepal.Length"] <- name
  return(temp_df)
}

produce_data_frame("newName")
#        newName Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
#2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `dplyr::rename` and `glue` there is little need to write such a function, as you can always do the following:

```
library(glue)
library(dplyr)
name <- "new_name"
rename(iris,"{name}" := Sepal.Length)
```

If a function is needed, there are many ways to implement it. The following is a generic function to rename a named vector or list (which includes data frames):

```
rename_named_obj <- function(named_obj,new_names) {
  setNames(named_obj,
    purrr::map2_chr(names(named_obj),
                    names(new_names)[match(names(named_obj),new_names)],
      ~ {
        ifelse(is.na(.y),.x,.y)
      })
  )
}
```

Giving the following results:

```
> new_iris_names <- list("new_name1"="Sepal.Length","new_name2"="Petal.Length")
> rename_named_obj(iris,new_iris_names) %>% colnames()
[1] "new_name1"   "Sepal.Width" "new_name2"   "Petal.Width" "Species"    
> rename_named_obj(setNames(1:5,colnames(df)),new_iris_names)
  new_name1 Sepal.Width   new_name2 Petal.Width     Species 
          1           2           3           4           5
```